# Xiaomi mi a2 lite stuck on headphones mode

Tags: audio, headphones, headphone-jack, xiaomi-mi-a2-lite

I was doing a mod with my car for an aux input mod but along the way I had to try different pinouts on my radio pcb to get the signal into it from my phone and unfortunately I damaged the phone audio circuit because when i unplug the jack it still puts the signal through headphones and speaker is out of play . I did find a temporary solution using lesser audioswitch app but when i restart the phone it switches again to headphones and I have to manually put it back to speaker mode .Does any one know a way to permanently set the audio output to loudspeaker as I will not use headphones anymore . By the way I physically removed the headphone port on my phone to be sure it is not in short or something. Any solution is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.